# Random y arrays

Tags: java, android, array

estaba trabajando con random y array y me surgieron 2 dudas sobre el tema.

1) Es posible crear 3 array, cada uno contiene imagenes, y con un random que elija una imagen de forma aleatoria del array y a su vez que el array de donde se toma la imagen tambien se elija al azar entre los 3 array que hay? No se si se entiende bien

2) Se puede hacer que una imagen tenga mas probabilidades de ser elegida sobre otra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.a)

> Es posible crear 3 array, cada uno contiene imagenes, y con un random
>   que elija una imagen de forma aleatoria del array

Si es posible, necesitamos usar la clase [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), crear una instancia y generar un numero aleatorio entero entre 0 y el último elemento de nuestro arreglo

```
Image[] arregloUno = new Image[10];
Image[] arregloDos = new Image[10];
Image[] arregloTres = new Image[10];

Random rnd = new Random();


Image imagenSelecionada = arregloUno[rnd.nextInt(arregloUno.length) ];
```

1.b)

> y a su vez que el array de donde se toma la imagen tambien se elija al
>   azar entre los 3 array que hay?

Si hay dos formas

1 - Crear un número aleatorio para elegir al azar el arreglo a usar

```
    int arregloSeleccionado = rnd.nextInt(3); //donde solo puede devolver 0 , 1 y 2 

    if(arregloSeleccionado == 0){
        return arregloUno[rnd.nextInt(arregloUno.length) ]; //elegimos uno
    }else if(arregloSeleccionado == 1){
        return arregloDos[rnd.nextInt(arregloUno.length) ]; //elegimos dos
    }else if(arregloSeleccionado == 2){
        return arregloTres[rnd.nextInt(arregloUno.length) ]; //elegimos tres
    }
```

o 2 - Crear un arreglo de arreglos y aplicar la misma lógica anterior, de elegir un elemento a través de su índice

```
    Object[] arreglos = new Object[3];
    arreglos[0] = arregloUno;
    arreglos[1] = arregloDos;
    arreglos[2] = arregloTres;

    arregloSeleccionado = arreglos[rnd.nextInt(arreglos.length) ];

    imagenSelecionada = arregloSeleccionado[rnd.nextInt(arregloSeleccionado.length) ];
```

---

2)

> Se puede hacer que una imagen tenga mas probabilidades de ser elegida
>   sobre otra?

Puede usar este truco:

Digamos que tenemos 3 imágenes y queremos que aparezcan con la siguiente probabilidad: 50 , 30 y 20.

Así que generamos un número al azar del 0 al 99 (como si fuera 1 a 100)

```
    int numeroAlatorio = rnd.nextInt(100);
```

Y en base a la probabilidad que queramos asignamos

```
    if(numeroAlatorio < 50){ // rango 0 a 49 (1-50) 
        //mostrar imagen1
    }else if(numeroAlatorio <80){ // rango 50 a 79 (51-80)
        //mostrar imagen2
    }else {// rango 80 a 99 (81-100)
        //mostrar imagen3
    }
```

La ventaja de hacerlo contra 100, es que en porcentajes es mas común el 100% que otros números